# How to insert an image with a caption into a custom element in CKEditor 5?

Tags: javascript, ckeditor, ckeditor5

I am trying to insert an image element inside a custom  tag. But image is not set properly. I customized image upload plugin of ckeditor.

Original upload plugin had these lines:

```
const imageElement = writer.createElement('image', { uploadId: loader.id });
const insertAtSelection = findOptimalInsertionPosition(doc.selection);
editor.model.insertContent(imageElement, insertAtSelection);
```

It's added image in dom tree like this:

```
<h2>TITLE</h2>
<figure class="image ck-widget ck-widget_selected" contenteditable="false">
    <img src="EXAMPLE/URL" title="" style="">
    <figcaption class="ck-editor__editable ck-editor__nested-editable ck-placeholder" contenteditable="true" data-placeholder=""><br data-cke-filler="true"></figcaption>
</figure>
```

I changed the plugin. When I upload image, this code lines are running:

```
const imageElement = writer.createElement('image', { uploadId: loader.id });
writer.appendElement('content', { 'guid': guid }, parent);
content = parent.getChild(parent.childCount - 1);
writer.append(imageElement, content);
writer.setSelection(content.getChild(content.childCount - 1), 0);
```

My code inserts image to dom tree like this:

```
<h2>TITLE</h2>
<content>
    <figure class="image ck-widget" contenteditable="false">
        <img>
    </figure>
</content>
```

How can I set image attributes and caption? I suspected the `insertContent`. I tried to run `insertContent` but I couldn't know what should be sent to `insertContent` as position parameter. If I use `findOptimalInsertionPosition(doc.selection)`, image is added outside the `<content>`.

Answer (score 3):

## Defining the schema

First of all, you need to make sure that `<image>` is allowed in your custom model element. If you registered it like this:

```
editor.model.schema.register( 'custom', {
    allowContentOf: '$root',
    allowWhere: '$block'
} );
```

Then you're fine. Since `<$root>` allows `<image>` inside, your `<custom>` will allow `<image>`.

You can read more about writing schema rules in the [Schema deep dive](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/framework/guides/deep-dive/schema.html) guide.

## Model structure

Now, you asked how to set the caption of the image. To understand that, you need to ask what's the structure of images in the model. The answer will be – it's very different from what you have in the view:

```
<image src="...">
    <caption>Caption text</caption>
</image>
```

That's the structure you want to create in order to insert an image with a caption.

## Inserting an image at a given location

The best method to insert an arbitrary content is [`editor.model.insertContent()`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_model-Model.html#function-insertContent) because it takes care of two things:

- setting the document selection to the desired (at least, from pasting-like cases) place after insertion,
- making sure that the content it's inserting is inserted in a place allowed by the schema (that's why we need to configure the schema first).

The [model writer methods](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_writer-Writer.html) do neither of these things, so unless you know exactly where the image should be inserted and how you want to set the selection, don't use them.

So, how to use `insertContent()`?

```
editor.model.change( writer => {
    const image = writer.createElement( 'image', { src: '...' } );
    const caption = writer.createElement( 'caption' );

    writer.appendText( 'Caption text', caption );
    writer.append( caption, image );


    // Option 1: If you have the <custom> element by reference:
    const positionInCustom = Position.createAt( customElement, 0 );

    editor.model.insertContent( image, positionInCustom );

    // In this case, we still have to set the selection because we haven't
    // passed document selection to `insertContent()` but a specific position.
    writer.setSelection( image, 'on' );


    // Option 2: Assuming that the document selection is somewhere
    // in your <custom> element you might do this (image will be inserted
    // at the document selection position):

    editor.model.insertContent( image );
} );
```

Refer to [`editor.model.insertContent()`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_model-Model.html#function-insertContent) documentation for more information on various ways it can be used.

Comment: I got this error: `_ckeditor_ckeditor5_engine_src_model_position__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_4__.default.createIn is not a function`

Comment: I'm sorry. It should be [`Position.createAt()`](https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor5/latest/api/module_engine_model_position-Position.html#static-function-createAt).

Comment: BTW, starting from December 2018 (the upcoming release, so most likely v11.2.0) this will be `writer.createPositionAt()`, so you won't need to import `Position` at all.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I tried to implement it. I created custom element in this scope before creating image element. But it wasn't working. I put a `setTimeout` delay method which includes `insertContent` code line. It is working now. I don't understand why I need the delay but otherwise it is not working. Maybe the reason is custom element is created just before inserting content.

Comment: this thing help me to understand the dom insertion, but im getting conversion-model-consumable-not-consumed for image model. other dom types are working fine.